# Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }

Tags: xamarin.android, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I'm doing a project using Cognitive Services, specifically computer vision, but at the moment of verifying the app it informs me that it is not possible to verify the image, and when validating the URL that it throws when creating the KEY API it shows me the following error:

**{"statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found"}**

Possibly because of this it does not verify the image that I want to validate. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Can you validate your endpoints and region. This error may caused due to the resource you are looking for is not available in specified region.

Comment: Hello how are you?. How can I know if this option is available in my region and how could I activate it to perform tests? I am located in Colombia.

Thank you very much

Comment: By region I mean to say azure region. This will be included in endpoint. Anyway are you using trial version of cognitive services?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing the demo with a trial version of cognitive services. But at the time of the tests, the Key were active.

Comment: You will need to double check with your endpoints. You are missing in endpoint details